# What is the quickest way to setup Instiki on Lion?

Tags: xcode

A few months ago I setup an Instiki wiki using Snow Leopard.
It took me quite a while, as I had to work some black magic to understand which version of ruby (plus gems/rails) I was supposed to install/update.

Now I've upgraded to Lion after formatting (bad idea huh?), and I'd like a new instiki up and running. So I thought: instead of wasting another day in trial and error I might ask if someone smarter and more knowledgeable has a quick and dirty way to do it (e.g. avoiding installing xcode tools!).

Cheers!

p.s. Instiki is very cool http://www.instiki.org/show/HomePage, especially if you like maths. Its user-friendliness is very far from Tiddlywiki, but I think it's much cooler.

p.p.s. please feel free to retag appropriately.

**EDIT** As pointed out, some more info might be useful.
When I try to run instiki (contained in a folder named taccuino) this is what it tells me

```
./Desktop/taccuino/config/../config/preinitializer.rb:20: Bundler couldn't find some gems.Did you run `bundle install`? (RuntimeError)
from ./Desktop/taccuino/config/boot.rb:28:in `load'
from ./Desktop/taccuino/config/boot.rb:28:in `preinitialize'
from ./Desktop/taccuino/config/boot.rb:10:in `boot!'
from ./Desktop/taccuino/config/boot.rb:124
from ./Desktop/taccuino/script/server:3:in `require'
from ./Desktop/taccuino/script/server:3
from ./Desktop/taccuino/instiki:6:in `load'
from ./Desktop/taccuino/instiki:6
```

Comment: It looks like there are binaries available for OS X, though they may be old. Have you tried [installing as a gem](http://www.instiki.org/show/Running+Instiki+as+Ruby+Gem)?

Comment: I'll have a look. Perhaps I should say that if I try to run instiki the error I receive says "Bundler couldn't find some gems".

Comment: I tried but I don't have a 'gems' command and typing 'gem instiki' gives me an error (command instiki not found). So it looks like I still have to resort to downloading all possible combinations of rubies!

Comment: Try `gem install instiki`, perhaps?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: OK, I was a bit dishonest. It actually fetched and installed a whole bunch of stuff (and it gave an error at the end, documentation stuff I think). I tried launching instiki and it gave me the same error as before. Then I updated the gems with 'gem update --system'. but same error again.

Comment: It'd help if you could actually add this info (and the exact errors) to the question.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/wiki/instiki/show/Installation) for proper instructions.

But, in brief,

```
ruby bundle
./instiki --daemon
```

I don't think there's anything quicker than that.